# Why doesn't my very simple jQuery work?

Tags: jquery, page-template

I just deployed a new Wordpress site. Everything looks good, now I'm setting up jQuery:

*Child theme* **functions.php:**

```
//enqueue scripts
function my_theme_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'myjs', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/my.js', array('jquery'),'1.0.0');
    wp_enqueue_script('myjs');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Page template **tpl-mypage.php**:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <?php wp_head(); ?>   
    </head>
<body>
    <div id=”test-script”></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The js file **my.js**:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    $("#test-script").html("Hello World");
})
```

This is NOT working. I can see my.js being loaded on Chrome>Inspect>Network.

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

The code seems fine. Please check by loading the script in the footer and also use the wp_footer in your .php file.

Answer (score 1):

Set the $in_footer argument to true when registering the script:

```
    wp_register_script( 'myjs', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/my.js', array('jquery'),'1.0.0', true);
```

And also call wp_footer(), as Mohsin mentioned:

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <?php wp_head(); ?>   
        </head>
    <body>
        <div id=”test-script”></div>
    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I have found the problem. It was THE QUOTE from <div id=”test-script”> versus $("#test-script").html("Hello World"); But thank you and @Mohsin Ghouri for pointing out my missing wp_footer(); I have added that too to make sure my js loads after the page.

Answer (score 0):

tried this way. No luck. need more help please. It works in locally but not inside wordpress.

My code : **myjquery.js**

```
   $(document).ready(function($) {
```

$('.item-type').click(function() {
    $('.item-type').removeClass('item-type-active');
  $(this).addClass('item-type-active');
  });

function rangeCalc(i) {
var totalPrice = 0;
var tariff = [{begin:1, price:1000}, ];
var tariffItem2 = [{begin:1, price:85}, {begin:3, price:80}, {begin:6, price:75}, {begin:11, price:70}, {begin:21, price:65}, {begin:61, price:60}];

tariff.forEach(function(num, item) {
    if (tariff[item].begin <= i) {
    totalPrice = tariff[item].price;
    $('.calc-total-price').text(i*totalPrice);
    $('.calc-price').text(totalPrice);
    };

});
};

$('.calc-range').on('input', function() {
    $('.calc-count').text(this.value);
  rangeCalc(this.value);
});

});

**loaded like this way. and shows it in page source.**

function load_js_assets() {
    if( is_page( 292 ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('myjquery', '/js/myjquery.js', array('jquery'), '', true);

```
}
```

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js_assets');